# What is the name of an Error that shows up when u type a number instead of string

Tags: python

I'm making a simple game that shows up "What number do you like" and if u write a number(for example "77") it should show up an EXCEPT but it doesn't
why?

```
your_name = input("What's your name: ")

this_year = 2019

your_age = int(input("How old are you: "))

year_born = this_year - your_age

print("Hello",your_name,".You are",your_age,"years old","\n\n")
year_when_you_were_born = print("That means that you were 
born",year_born)

hundred_year = year_born + 100

print("And that means that you are gonna be 100 years old at the year 
of",hundred_year)

number = int(input("What number do you like: "))

try:
    question = str(input("Do you wanna print your name that many times: 
"))
except ValueError:
    print("I don't get it,type words not numbers")

else:
    if question == "yes":
        word = your_name * question
        print(word)
```

Comment: Why would you want an exception if you type in a number?

Comment: You won't get an exception if you type a number in response to a prompt for a string. That is because all sequences of digits form a subset of the set of strings. So you will have to do the validation yourself. For example `if question.isdigit(): raise ValueError("I expected a string not a number")`.

Answer (score 0):

`number = int(input("What number do you like: "))` takes the input and converts it to an `int`. So 77 is fine. However, letters can not be converted to a int, so that will throw a ValueError. For that the line needs to be inside the `try` block:

```
try:
    number = int(input("What number do you like: "))
except ValueError:
    print("I don't get it,type numbers not words")
```

Note that `question = str(input("Do you wanna print your name that many times: "))` will not throw a ValueError, because both letters and numbers can be converted to a string. So you don't have to put it in the 'try'-block, it is better placed in the 'else' block:

```
try:
    number = int(input("What number do you like: "))
except ValueError:
    print("I don't get it,type numbers not words")
else:
    question = str(input("Do you wanna print your name that many times: "))
    if question == "yes":
        word = your_name * question
        print(word)
```